# How to delete newline and character at the start of line using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, carriage-return

I need to delete a newline with exact character at the beginning of the line.

For example, I have new.txt file which contains the following lines:

```
"AAA"AAA
"BBB
"""BBB
"CCC"CCC
```

Expected result is:

```
"AAA"AAA
"BBB"BBB
"CCC"CCC
```

I tried using `sed` but it is not working.

```
sed -i -e 's/\n"""/"/g' new.txt
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Perl.

```
perl -i -0777pe 's/\n"""/"/' new.txt
```

Output to `new.txt`:

```
"AAA"AAA
"BBB"BBB
"CCC"CCC
```

Comment: thx for the suggestion,
but when i try your solution,

this is the result when i tried `vi new.txt`
`
"AAA"AAA
"BBB^M"BBB
"CCC"CCC
there is `^M` in the midlle

Comment: Your file was created on a Windows system. Try this: `perl -i -0777pe 's/\r\n"""/"/' new.txt`

Comment: I don't know if it was your intention, but `-0pe` changes the input record separator from `"\n"` to `"\0"` (a NUL byte). If you meant to slurp the whole file, try `-0777`.

Comment: @melpomene: Thank you for this hint! I've updated my answer and comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use **tr** to replace the *\r\n*. Use the **sed** command and then replace the *\r\n* back. *\r* is there since your file has Windows line endings.

```
tr '\r' '\t' < new.txt | tr '\n' '\f' | sed -e 's/\t\f"""/"/' | tr '\f' '\n' | tr '\t' '\r'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/\n"""/"/;P;D' file
```

Append the next line to the current line. If the pattern space now contains `\n"""` replace it by `"` and then print/delete the first line in the pattern space and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
$ cat new.txt
"AAA"AAA
"BBB
"""BBB
"CCC"CCC

$ sed ':x;N;s/\n""//;bx' new.txt
"AAA"AAA
"BBB"BBB
"CCC"CCC
```

[GNU - sed manual - joining lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Joining-lines)

T.